# While using DatatimeIndex, it gives below error:__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start' datetimeindex

Tags: python

If I use this command:

```
#df = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2019-01-01 06:30',freq='W',periods=3,tz='Asia/Calcutta')
```

It gives this error:

> __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start' datetimeindex

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Use [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) instead.

Comment: With a `#` in front, it does nothing. `pd` is undefined. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) does not take `start` as an argument. you can use [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) as @Vishnudev suggested

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), this constructor does not have a `start` argument.
Instead, you could use the `pd.date_range` like below:

```py
 df = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 06:30', freq='W', periods=3, tz='Asia/Calcutta')
```